# Eclipse, how to sort variables in Debug Perspective

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse Neon 2 I'm hoping to be able to sort variables alphabetically that appear in the Variables window?  There are so many variables in a class I'm debugging that it's tiresome to search through such a long list for the variable of interest.

Specifically the Eclipse window is called (x)= Variables and appears in the upper right in default Debug Perspective, see linked image.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to change that sort order.  What you might me interested in is the "Expressions" view where you can type in certain variable names(or even expressions) and see what their value is.  You can get this to show by clicking Window -> Show View -> Other..., then it's under the debug group.

Comment: Although I have Neon 3 (was previously Neon 2 before updating some time back), if you do a right-click inside the `variables` window, is there not a `Sort by name` option in the context menu that appears? For me, that option appears as the first entry in the context menu.

Comment: Yes, Expressions is somewhat helpful, thanks.  There isn't a Sort by name or other sort submenu in my version of Eclipse.  Maybe I'll upgrade to a newer version.